# jQuery help for WordPress: add class on scroll offset top

Tags: jquery, wordpress

This is giving me grey hair.

I want to add a class to an element when it hits the top of my screen. The code works in my codepen and if i enter it in the console in chrome, but not then i add to wordpress. All my other scripts works fine though, what to to?

What all the scripts i've found does is that the add the class immediately on scroll and that's it - it won't remove it or add it when or suppose to.

I've found several scripts and if you have a better on, fell free to add it instead.

```js
(function($) {
  var item = $('.item').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function(){    
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > item){ 
          $('.item').addClass('addclass'); 
      }
      else{
          $('.item').removeClass('addclass');
      }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: all ease .3s;
}

#wrapper {
  background: pink;
  height: 2000px;
}

.navigation {
  height: 60px;
  background: lime;
  
}
.block {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 300px;
}
.item {
  background: purple;
  height: 300px; 
}
.item.addclass {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="navigation">
        <!-- There are some list elements here -->
    </div>
    <div class="block"> BLOCK</div>
    <div class="item">ITEM</div> 
    <div class="block"> BLOCK</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After more hours of trial and error i found this little snippet, which are doing the job perfectly:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var objectSelect = $(".item");
    var objectPosition = objectSelect.offset().top;
    if (scroll > objectPosition) {
        $(".item").addClass("change");
    } else {
        $(".item").removeClass("change");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to simplify things and don't care much about old browsers, I'd recommend using [position: sticky](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)

You just need a few lines of codes to get it done. Read more about positions and more examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```js
(function($) {

    var item = $('.item'),
 top = item.offset().top;
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop() > top ? item.addClass('sticky') : item.removeClass('sticky');
 });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: all ease .3s;
}

#wrapper {
  background: pink;
  height: 2000px;
}

.navigation {
  height: 60px;
  background: lime;

}
.block {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 300px;
}
.item {
  background: purple;
  height: 300px; 
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="navigation">
        <!-- There are some list elements here -->
    </div>
    <div class="block"> BLOCK</div>
    <div class="item">ITEM</div> 
    <div class="block"> BLOCK</div>
</div>
```